# How to check if a data is present in SQL Server table column where the data re inserted in inverted commas

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have added some data values as 'a','b','c' (same as this) in a SQL Server table column. How can I check if a or b or c is present in this table value or not?

Comment: You are looking for [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: You should **never** store more than one value into a single column cell - this violates even the **first normal form** of database design. A cell should contain at most **one value** - or none - but never multiple. That causes nothing but trouble and headaches for scenarios exactly like the one you're facing right now..... **don't do it!**

Comment: Please share your table schema, input data and expected output result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your column value looks like:

```
[YourColumn]
-------------
'a','b'
'a'
'a','b','c'
```

The following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE Contains([YourColumn], 'a') 
OR
SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE [YourColumn] LIKE '%a%'
```

However, unless the possible values for this column are very-very excessive, it is not recommended to store them like this in a single column. Instead, have different flag columns for each value. Again, do it only if the possible values are limited.

Hope this helps.